# How do I delete duplicate contacts programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I have an app that inserts contacts to a phone, from an XML file on my web server. The app re-inserts the contacts once a day so I have the latest contacts and numbers etc. However, I want to delete all the contacts from the first insert so there are no duplicates.

All the code that I've tried keeps resulting in all the contacts being deleted, before the list is inserted. So this removes other contacts that are not part of the XML list as well.

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < mainList.getLength(); temp++) {

Node mainNode = mainList.item(temp);
Element eElement = (Element) mainNode;
list.add(getChildElementContent(eElement, "NAME") + ": " + 
getChildElementContent(eElement, "NUMBER"));
System.out.println(list.get(temp));

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new 
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    null, null, null, null);
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    try{
        String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
        System.out.println("The uri is " + uri.toString());
        cr.delete(uri, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME + "=" + getChildElementContent(eElement,"NAME"), null);
        System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        System.out.println( getChildElementContent(eElement,"NAME"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

The where clause should only delete contacts that have the same name as contacts in my XML file. But it deletes every contact on the phone.

Comment: Rather than deleting and reuploadijng, update the existing contacts.  Deleting and recreating could screw up a variety of other apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this :

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");
    String lastnumber = "0";

    if (cur.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            String number = null;
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]
                { id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.e("lastnumber ", lastnumber);
                    Log.e("number", number);

                    if (number.equals(lastnumber))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lastnumber = number;

                        Log.e("lastnumber ", lastnumber);
                        int type = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                        switch (type)
                        {
                            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                Log.e("Not Inserted", "Not inserted");
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:

                                databaseHandler.insertContact(id, name, lastnumber, 0);
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                Log.e("Not Inserted", "Not inserted");
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                }
                pCur.close();
            }

        }
    }
```

i have inserted data in sqlite database first and then Write select query with group by name.

Comment: This doesn't actually delete anything? I need to delete duplicates from the list when I re-insert from the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with the comment, you should update your contacts, instead of deleting all and the inserting them again.

However, if you're still into doing that, you need to make sure you insert all your app's contacts under your app's own `ACCOUNT_NAME`/`ACCOUNT_TYPE`.
Then you can easily delete the `RawContact`s coming from your app only.

The problem with your code is that you're deleting whole Contacts, you should instead be deleting RawContacts only.

See here how you should be inserting your app's RawContacts: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts#operations
you'll need to find a unique string for `ACCOUNT_TYPE` so there won't be a clash with other apps.

Deleting all your app's `RawContacts` is then easy via:

```
String selection = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "=" + myAccountType;
getContentResolver().delete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, selection, null);
```

Comment: What should myAccountType be? When I set the value of it as "Company", no contacts are added.

Comment: it's usually your package name + something, e.g. `com.company.android.sync-account`

Comment: account-name is usually used for a user-specific account, e.g. for Google account it may be something like: ACCOUNT_TYPE = `com.google.sync-account`, ACCOUNT_NAME `user-name@gmail.com`

Comment: I've tried all sorts of ways to delete, but none work. Can you suggest an alternative method?